# A net in $L^1(\mu)$ which converges vaguely in $M(X)$ to the point mass at $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm working through Folland, Problem 7.25, which states:

> Let $\mu$ be a Radon measure on $X$ such that every nonempty open set has positive measure (e.g. Lebesgue measure). For each $x \in X$ there is a net $\{ f_\alpha \} \in L^1(\mu)$ that converges vaguely in $M(X)$ to the point mass at $x$. If $X$ is first countable, the net can be taken to be a sequence. (Consider functions of the form $\mu(U)^{-1} 1_U$.)

I have a rough idea of how to prove this in the case of Lebesgue measure $m$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Let me outline the argument. Fix an $x \in \mathbb{R}$. For every $n \geq 1$, let $B_{n^{-1}}(x)$ denote an open ball around $x$ with radius $n^{-1}$. As per the hint, define $d\mu_n = \frac{1}{m(B_{n^{-1}}(x))} 1_{B_{n^{-1}}(x)}(\cdot) \; dm$. Let $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$. We want to show that $\int f \; d\mu_n \longrightarrow f(x)$. This is the case, since
$$
  | \int f \; d\mu_n - f(x) | = | \frac{1}{m(B_{n^{-1}}(x))}  \int_{B_{n^{-1}}(x)} (f(y) - f(x)) \; dy | \leq \sup_{y \in B_{n^{-1}}(x)} |f(y) - f(x)| \longrightarrow 0 \:,
$$
where the RHS tends to zero by the continuity of $f$ at $x$.

To extend the argument to first countable LCH space, I think it would be sufficient to find a sequence of open sets $\{ V_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\mu(V_n)$'s are finite and $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n = \{x\}$. For every $x \in X$, a first countable space has a countable collection of open sets $\{O_n\}$ which form the neighborhood base. I was thinking to argue that the intersection of these open sets is the desired collection $\{V_n\}$, but I am stuck on how one could ensure that the $O_n$'s are (eventually) finite in measure.

EDIT: Thanks to Norbert I've made some progress. Let $U \ni x$ be an open neighborhood containing $x$ (one must exist since we can take $U = X$). Since $X$ is an LCH space, there exists a compact $K$ such that $x \in K \subset U$. But then there exists a precompact open $V$ such that $x \in K \subset V \subset \overline{V} \subset U$. Since $\mu$ is a Radon measure, $\mu(V) \leq \mu(\overline{V}) < \infty$. Letting $\{V_n\}$ denote our neighborhood base at $x$, the sets $Q_n = V_n \cap V$ are (a) open and (b) finite in measure. Once you argue that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} Q_n = \{x\}$, the proof is pretty much done for the first countable LCH case I think.

Comment: At the verry begining choose an open set $U$ of finite measure containing $x$.   Then intersect all $V_n$'s with this $U$.

Comment: Norbert: how do I know I can find such a $U$? What if $\mu(E) = \infty$ if $E$ is not empty and $0$ if $E$ is empty? EDIT: that was a dumb comment by me-- a Radon measure is one such that $\mu(E)$ is finite for any compact set. I think this is enough to get the open $U$.